# Adobe Shockwave Player install problem

Tags: windows-7, installation

Win7 Home Prem 32bit
I have admin rights

I am trying to install Adobe Shockwave Player but am getting the following message almost as soon as i click on the Shockwave_Installer_Slim.exe

**Error Opening File for writing**

**C:\windows\system32\adobe\director\np32dsw.dll**

It then gives me the option to Abort, Retry or Ignore.

I figured ignoring probably isn't sensible and retry won't go any further.

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Which browser(s) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.

I managed to get it working by downloading and installing

**Shockwave_Installer_Full.exe**

instead of the **Shockwave_Installer_Slim.exe**

Am using Firefox 3.6.6 to answer an earlier reply

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following helps:

Download this [file](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/shockwave/default/english/win95nt/latest/Shockwave_Installer_Slim.exe) and save to disk. Close all your browser windows, then run the downloaded installer.

Answer (score 0):

Run the program as administrator. (Right-click, "Run as administrator")